# how to get object in array list php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have an array of ways to retrieve paper objects? I try foreach,Trying to get property 'sample_url' of non-object,and Illegal string offset 'sample_url' , how get sample_url in object paper?

```
 "active_joins2": [
    {
      "join_registration_number": "SS-006672-I-ID",
      "join_status": "checked",
      "join_tag": "9#science#indonesia#Primary 3",
      "student_id": 7502,
       "paper": {
          "sample_id": 57,
          "sample_title": "Science Indonesia Primary 3",
          "sample_url":"http:google.com/abc/sample/1548989381.pdf",
          "sample_tag": "9#science#indonesia#Primary 3"
       }
    },
    {
      "join_registration_number": "MS-006687-I-ID",
      "join_status": "checked",
      "join_tag": "9#math#indonesia#Primary 3",
      "student_id": 7502,
      "paper": {
         "sample_id": 47,
         "sample_title": "Math Indonesia Primary 3",
         "sample_url":"http://google.com/sample/1548988991.pdf",
         "sample_tag": "9#math#indonesia#Primary 3"
       }
   }
]
```

in blade view

```
   @foreach ($item['active_joins2'] as $row => $val)
       @php 
          $string = str_replace('#',' ',$val['join_tag']);
          $exString = explode(" ",$string);
       @endphp       
       <a href="{{}}" style="text-decoration:none;">
           <div class="card jismo-practice-paper mx-auto mb-3">
               <div class="card-body row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                    <div class="subject" style='text-transform: capitalize'>{{$exString[1]}}</div>
                                    <div class="language" style='text-transform: capitalize'>{{$exString[2]}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                    <div class="grade">{{$exString[3]}}</div>
                                    <div class="gradenumber">{{$exString[4]}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </a>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Code snippet is actually a JSON, do you work with JSON or with php array?

Comment: This has already been made an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do simply with `json_decode()`, **Also your json string is missing starting and ending curly braces** i.e `{ }`

```
$array = json_decode($object,1);
foreach($array['active_joins2'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['paper']['sample_url'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/AbsLS

Comment: active_joins2 is an array not an object

Comment: @MuhamadRahmatSetiawan did you check my working demo?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is json, you can use `json_decode` function and after that use that in php like array or std object
[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)